# How to remove BOM characters from a string in Python 3.9.6?

Tags: python, csv, encoding, python-3.9, byte-order-mark

I have a bytestring that I'm supposed to send to a **zipfile** using Pyhton's built in `zipfile.writestr` but in the beginning of each of the files there's a small (14-15) chars BOM character string and one big one at the end of the entire file, the final **csv** file looks like this(example):

```
filename1

(BOM characters)Column1, Column2, Column3

data1, data2, data3

data4, data5, data6

filename2

(BOM characters)Column1, Column2, Column3

data1, data2, data3
(BOM characters)
```

I've tried using `.decode("utf-8-sig")` but it showed no difference.

Comment: What are these BOM characters?  UTF-8-SIG/UTF-16 BOMs are only three characters long.

Comment: @snakecharmerb thanks for commenting, I was able to resolve the issue however, check my answer :)